# Asp.Net show alert on session timeout

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have got an Asp.Net MVC application. This is just an approach so I can't provide code.

Basically what I want to achieve is if the session is over show an alert on whatever page the user is on.

[image]

The picture from Azure shows what I want to achieve (but this is farther, I want to start with displaying an alert first).

So is there a function or anything provided by asp.net detecting if the session is over? And secondly how would I display an alert?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no specific function in asp.net that notifies the user that the session is over or going to end. But this functionality is seen nowadays in many websites.
The session is started by the server when a postback request is received. When there is no user action for a specific period of time, session expires. You can use javascript alert to show popup to the user regarding session timeout.

I will suggest 2 ways :

> 1. Run a timer in client side and notify the user when it is about to expire. For eg. if your session timeout is 5 min, you can probably
>      notify the user after 4 min that the session will expire in 1 min if
>      no action is done.
> 2. The second approach is to initiate a post-back request to the controller automatically or when user clicks ok button on an
>      alert(Your session will expire soon and you will be logged out. Do you
>      wish to extend the session?)

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, there is no easy answer to this. The reason is that if you were to ping the server to check the session, that action would actually renew the session timeout, unless you configure the service to not access the session - which means you need yet another tracking mechanism. The "fake" way is to set a JavaScript time that equals the session timeout. You would need to reset that timer on any ajax call.

The more involved solution is to use a persistent connection technology like SignalR that notifies a subscriber on session_timeout.